# Error Installing Wifi Driver on Yoga 13 (when "make)

Tags: wireless, drivers, make

My problem is with installing the driver:

I am currently running Kali Linux on my Yoga 13 and have followed the steps here: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H3WdsSHo5Sw

Which basically told me to download the github sourcecode as a .zip file onto a computer that has internet connection -> unzip on the computer and transfer to Yoga13 via usb:

I did that and when I use `make` after `cd rtl8723au-master/` I get this error:

```
make ARCH=X86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/3.7-trunk-amd64/build M=root/rtl8723au-master modules
make: *** /lib/modules/3.7-trunk-amd64/build: No such file or directory. Stop. 
make: *** [modules] Error 2
```

Again.. installing Kali on a standard Yoga 13 with sourcecode from https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8723au

Answer (score 0):

This error usually indicates you have not installed required kernel headers. With a temporary wired ethernet connection, please do:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

Then try the 'make' step again.

Comment: I don't have any internet connection on that laptop, what do I do?

Comment: I mean the Yoga 13 does not have an ethernet port, I do not own an ethernet to usb adapter, bluetooth doesnt work

Comment: I probably should have flagged this as off-topic because it's not about Ubuntu. You will have to find linux headers matching your running kernel and transfer them on a USB stick. I can be of no further assistance. Sorry.